# How to compare timestamp stored in Data Extension as Text

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I am downloading a Report into from Salesforce Cloud into a SFMC Data Extension. The report consists of contacts that have signed up Today.

A sample data of the 'Created Date Backend' field is : 31.03.2017 05:11

The date timestamp is stored as 'Created Date Backend'. However the report gets imported to the DE only when this field is of Type TEXT in the DE. The data extension where this value is stored is : [Contacts Signed Up Today]. The requirement is to configure an automated email send to Contacts who signed up After the office hrs.

I am trying to select the contacts who signed up after 18 and before 6 this query but its not working. Its not selecting anything, can anyone help?

```
Select 
 *
from [Contacts Signed Up Today] 
where
([Created Date Backend]  >= DATEADD(HOUR,18,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110))
AND [Created Date Backend]  <= DATEADD(HOUR,6,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()+1,110)))
```

Comment: I got it myself :)

where
SUBSTRING(a.[Created Date Backend],12,2)>=18 that works for me

Comment: i would recommend posting this as an answer and then in 48 hrs marking it as correct so anyone else with this issue can easily find the solution.